# undefined reference to `initsrc' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: ld, ncurses

$ gcc -o autott autott.c -lncurses
/tmp/cciOHP4W.o: In function `main':
autott.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to`initsrc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have installed ncurses, but it still return this error. Why?

Comment: $ ls /usr/include/ncurses*
/usr/include/ncurses_dll.h  /usr/include/ncurses.h

I can find ncurses.h under /usr/include

Answer (score 0):

The initialization function is named [**`initscr`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr), not `initsrc`.

(You might also have forgotten to list the library when linking, e.g., `-lncurses`).